# Can't compile Arduino CapSense example

Tags: compilation, arduino

I'm trying to work with the [CapSense library for Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Main/CapSense). However, I can't manage to run the example included with the package, called "CapSenseSketch". When I try just opening the file and running it (I've tried both Arduino 1.0 and 1.0.1), I get a compiler error that says 'CapSense does not name a type", and also

```
CapSenseSketch.cpp:1:22: error: CapSense.h: No such file or directory
CapSenseSketch:11: error: 'CapSense' does not name a type
CapSenseSketch:12: error: 'CapSense' does not name a type
CapSenseSketch:13: error: 'CapSense' does not name a type
CapSenseSketch.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
CapSenseSketch:17: error: 'cs_4_2' was not declared in this scope
CapSenseSketch.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
CapSenseSketch:24: error: 'cs_4_2' was not declared in this scope
CapSenseSketch:25: error: 'cs_4_6' was not declared in this scope
CapSenseSketch:26: error: 'cs_4_8' was not declared in this scope
```

There is an include statement at the top of the code,

```
#include <CapSense.h>
```

and I thought that would be the problem, so I changed the brackets to quotes and still got an error saying "Error compiling" and:

```
CapSenseSketch.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
CapSenseSketch.cpp:15: undefined reference to `CapSense::CapSense(unsigned char, unsigned char)'
CapSenseSketch.cpp:16: undefined reference to `CapSense::CapSense(unsigned char, unsigned char)'
CapSenseSketch.cpp:17: undefined reference to `CapSense::CapSense(unsigned char, unsigned char)'
CapSenseSketch.cpp.o: In function `loop':
CapSenseSketch.cpp:28: undefined reference to `CapSense::capSense(unsigned char)'
CapSenseSketch.cpp:29: undefined reference to `CapSense::capSense(unsigned char)'
CapSenseSketch.cpp:30: undefined reference to `CapSense::capSense(unsigned char)'
CapSenseSketch.cpp.o: In function `setup':
CapSenseSketch.cpp:21: undefined reference to `CapSense::set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(unsigned long)'
```

Any ideas? I've worked with CapSense on another computer and changing the brackets to quotes worked fine that time, but it doesn't seem to be doing much now.

Comment: Are you getting the errors when you check the syntax or when you try to compile and upload?

Comment: Just when I press 'verify'. I fixed the problem yesterday, though. In the arduino IDE, to use external scripts, you have to go to "sketch > add file" for every file you want to use. In my case, I was using a .h file, and a .cpp file that the .h file used. I had only added the .h file in this way, so the arduino wasn't seeing the necessary code in the .cpp file, though it was included in the .h file.

Comment: Also, for anyone using CapSense004, the type was renamed to CapacitiveSensor from CapSense.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently including external files works a bit differently in the arduino ide. It's not enough to simply have an include statement at the top of your code, you must instead manually go to sketch > add file for every external file you want to use. In my case, I only did this for one out of the two files I was trying to use.