# Can't compile CapacitiveSensor example in Arduino

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, libraries, arduino-ide, intel-galileo

I am trying to use the [Capacitive Sensors Library](http://playground.arduino.cc//Main/CapacitiveSensor) from the Arduino Playground with Arduino 1.5.3 for Intel Galileo.

While trying to compile the example Sketch of the library with nothing touched I get the following error:

```
Arduino: 1.5.3 (Windows 7), Board: "Intel® Galileo"
```

> CapacitiveSensor.cpp: In constructor
>   'CapacitiveSensor::CapacitiveSensor(uint8_t, uint8_t)':
>   CapacitiveSensor.cpp:30:63: error: 'F_CPU' was not declared in this
>   scope CapacitiveSensor.cpp:43:10: error: 'PinDescription' has no
>   member named 'ulPin' CapacitiveSensor.cpp:44:10: error:
>   'PinDescription' has no member named 'pPort'
>   CapacitiveSensor.cpp:45:31: error: 'portModeRegister' was not declared
>   in this scope CapacitiveSensor.cpp:46:9: error: base operand of '->'
>   is not a pointer CapacitiveSensor.cpp:48:9: error: 'PinDescription'
>   has no member named 'ulPin' CapacitiveSensor.cpp:49:10: error:
>   'PinDescription' has no member named 'pPort'
>   CapacitiveSensor.cpp:51:9: error: base operand of '->' is not a
>   pointer CapacitiveSensor.cpp:52:12: error: base operand of '->' is not
>   a pointer CapacitiveSensor.cpp:55:18: error: 'noInterrupts' was not
>   declared in this scope CapacitiveSensor.cpp:57:16: error: 'interrupts'
>   was not declared in this scope CapacitiveSensor.cpp: In member
>   function 'void CapacitiveSensor::set_CS_Timeout_Millis(long unsigned
>   int)': CapacitiveSensor.cpp:133:73: error: 'F_CPU' was not declared in
>   this scope CapacitiveSensor.cpp: In member function 'int
>   CapacitiveSensor::SenseOneCycle()': CapacitiveSensor.cpp:141:18:
>   error: 'noInterrupts' was not declared in this scope
>   CapacitiveSensor.cpp:151:16: error: 'interrupts' was not declared in
>   this scope

I downloaded the files and imported the "CapacitiveSensor"-Folder into (I did those steps one after the other, not at the same time.):

1. The libraries folder under Documents/arduino/.
2. The libraries folder in the arduino folder where the arduino.exe is stored.
3. Onto arduino-1.5.3/hardware/libraries/ (because this is mentioned on the site where I downloaded it)
4. And I tried this: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638989/cant-compile-arduino-capsense-example) Because it seemed to be the same error as I had. But it didnt work.

I also deleted my Arduino and reinstalled it.

Anyone has an Idea?
Thanks in advance,
Clemens

Comment: This question should probably be asked on the http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ site which is more likely to have Arduino users on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question on the Arduino forum but I don't know if your issue is exactly the same:   [[FIXED][CapacitiveSensor] Can't compile with Due (port manipulation)](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=147092.0)

It doesn't look like the Arduino folks are very responsive.  The user modified register names and eventually put his own library out there.

*"...changed the uint8_t registers to RwReg (compiler doesn't complain) and I replaced the use of portModeRegister(PIN) with simple pinMode(PIN, MODE) calls (it's slower but it works)."*